# Why is the scipy.coherence function faster when used with an array compared to a matrix?

Tags: python, performance, scipy, signal-processing

Recently I started the refactoring of my code for signal processing. One part of this analysis is coherence computation. The former realization is:

```
def cohergramm_old(t, Data, Sig_names, wind_len, coh_len, overlap_spec, overlap_coh):
    Fs = 1./(t[1] - t[0])
    spec_coh = []
    for i in range(np.int((len(Data) - wind_len) / (wind_len - overlap_spec)) + 1):

        if i == 0:
            freq, coh_temp = signal.coherence(Data[Sig_names[0]][0 : wind_len].to_numpy(), Data[Sig_names[1]][0 : wind_len].to_numpy(), fs = Fs, window = 'hamming', nperseg = coh_len, noverlap = overlap_coh)
        else:
            index_start = i * (wind_len - overlap_spec)
            index_finish = i * (wind_len - overlap_spec) + wind_len
            freq , coh_temp = signal.coherence(Data[Sig_names[0]][index_start : index_finish].to_numpy(), Data[Sig_names[1]][index_start:index_finish].to_numpy(), fs = Fs, window = 'hamming', nperseg = coh_len, noverlap = overlap_coh)
        spec_coh.append(coh_temp)
    return freq, np.transpose(spec_coh)
```

In few words, I split signal by window and just use `scipy.coherence` for each sample.

After refactoring it looks like this:

```
def cohergram_new(t:np.ndarray, sig1:np.ndarray, sig2:np.ndarray, window_t:float, overlap_t:float, coher_win:float, coher_overlap:float):
    
    fs = 1/(t[1] - t[0])
    window_len = int(window_t*fs)
    overlap_len = int(overlap_t*fs)
    coher_win_len = int(coher_win*fs)
    coher_overlap_len = int(coher_overlap*fs)
    
    stride = sig1.strides;
    
    res_shape = (int((t.size - window_len)/(window_len-overlap_len) + 1), window_len)
    sig1_strided = as_strided(sig1, shape=res_shape, strides=(stride[0]*(window_len - overlap_len), stride[0]))
    sig2_strided = as_strided(sig2, shape=res_shape, strides=(stride[0]*(window_len - overlap_len), stride[0]))
    coher = scipy.signal.coherence(sig1_strided, sig2_strided, fs=fs, nperseg=coher_win_len, noverlap=coher_overlap_len, axis=1, window='hamming')
    return t, *coher
```

In this case I just form two matrices by windowing the signal (each line is an window length sample of signal) and apply the `scipy.coherence` to entire matrix (coherence is vectorized of course)

As a result I got the same computation results by using these methodes, but the former function is two times faster on average. It is the surprising result for me cause I tought the built-in `scipy` function is faster apriori.

Do you have any idea why it is the case?

UPD: some code for tests:

````
    t = np.arange(0, 10**4, 0.01)
    sig1 = np.sin(10*2*np.pi*t) + np.random.rand(t.size)
    sig2 = np.sin(10*2*np.pi*t + np.pi/2) + np.random.rand(t.size)
    Data = pd.DataFrame({"name1":sig1, "name2":sig2})
    fs=1/(t[1]-t[0])
    window_len = int(100*fs)
    overlap_len = int(90*fs)
    coher_win_len = int(10*fs)
    coher_overlap_len = int(9*fs)
    
    
    f_mat_old, cohermat_old = cohergramm_old(t, Data, ["name1", "name2"], window_len, coher_win_len, overlap_len, coher_overlap_len)
    t_mat, f_mat, cohermat = cohergramm_new(t, sig1, sig2, 100, 90, 10, 9)```
````

Comment: use `line_profiler`, it may give you a hint - maybe second function is not spending most of the time in `coherence` function (that's my guess)

Comment: @dankal444 thank for your tip! It spends almost all time in coherence, I checked it.

Comment: Having some idea of the array shapes may help, along with the `i` iteration size. It's hard to picture, just from reading the code, what the `as_strided` is producing, and how that replaces the loop.  But it's well known that a 'few' interations on a complex task can be faster than the equivalent whole-array operation. It depends on memory size, though `as_strided` complicates such a generalization.

Comment: Aren't you using the same scipy function in both cases?

Comment: What do you mean by 'array' vs 'matrix'? `coherence` says inputs are supposed to be arrays (time series).  It doesn't say whether they have to be 1d or can be 2d. And if 2d, whether it does any reshaping.

Comment: @hpaulj I mean array is a 1d np.ndarray and matrix is 2d np.ndarray. The ```scipy.coherence``` indeed works both with 1d and 2d arrays. the problems is it is faster to call this function N times (let us work with a matrix MxN, where M - number of columns, N - number of rows ) than just apply it to entire matrix

Comment: yes that happens.  usually we blame it on more complicated memory management in the 2d case, but details depend a lot on size of M and N.  `as_strided` produces a view, but if coherence does any sort of reshaping, that can force a copy, blowing up memory usage.  So without sample inputs and the ability to explore the timings for diffrent sizes, it's hard to do anything beyond handwaving.

Comment: @hpaulj ok, got it. Added some test data to the questions update

Comment: Can't reproduce this - for me cohergram_new is 2x faster than cohergram_old. However, I may be using a different value for `t` than you, since I had to guess what to use.

Comment: @NickODell, Sorry, I forgot to add t array. What t did you use?

Comment: @NickODell I what package did you use to measure time spent on the function execution?

Comment: @MihTo I used `t = np.linspace(0, 1000, 10000)`. To time the function, I used [timeit](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit).

Comment: @NickODell ok, thank you. Starting with ```10**7``` elements the execution time becomes the same for both cases

Comment: When I replace the call to scipy.signal.coherence with a for loop, it gets faster. That seems really strange. That contradicts what I know about Python optimizations. It makes me think that it must be computing something different than just calling coherence once for each row.